# std::cin sometimes hangs, sometimes repeats forever after invalid input

Tags: c++

In this case, when the line marked `hang point` receives invalid input, eg. `abc`, it repeats the inner do-while loop and hangs upon reaching that line again.

```
// figure 1
std::string s;
do {
    do {
        std::cout<<"s = ";
        std::getline(std::cin, s);
    } while (s == "");
    double d;
    std::cout<<"d = ";
    do {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin>>d; // hang point
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    } while (std::cin.fail());
} while (s != "exit");
```

In this case the program skips over that line and repeats the do-while loop forever.

```
// figure 2
double d;
do {
    std::cout<<"d = ";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin>>d; // skip point
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
} while (std::cin.fail());
```

Why?

Originally I was going to ask why `figure 1` hangs, and in the process of trying to simplify the example I came up with `figure 2`, and found that it didn't hang, but repeated forever. I don't understand why either `figure 1` or `figure 2` do what they do.

Edit: I've been causing `cin` to fail by entering alphabetical data at the prompt that I wrote for myself. eg.

```
s = something
d = 3
s = something
d = a
```

Comment: What input are you providing to `std::cin`?

Comment: The input that I've been using to make `std::cin>>d;` fail is usually a single alphabetical character eg. `a` or `r` or something.

Comment: Right but how exactly are you inputting it? Directly in the terminal? Redirection with a file? Copy your input and output to your question.

Comment: Directly in the terminal, at the prompt I provided myself.

Comment: `clear()` shouldn't be called from the top, it should be right before the `ignore()` call.

Comment: @0x499602D2 While this fixes the hanging problem, it won't allow re-entering of that while loop in case the user enters something incorrect for the value of d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure2: You have to call cin.clear() before cin.ignore(). Otherwise, cin.ignore won't do anything because cin is still in an error state.

```
double d;
do {
    if (std::cin.fail()) {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    std::cout<<"d = ";
    std::cin>>d;
} while (std::cin.fail());
```

Comment: Please use the numeric limit instead of an arbitrary constant.

Comment: @MikePrecup Thanks, forgot about that :P

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that you're resetting the flags, but the cin buffer is still full. So when it re-enters the loop, 'd' is automatically reassigned the letter value (say, the 'abc' you entered at the terminal) automatically. Thus the fail flag will then be reset, and the cycle repeats all over again.

Here's the fixed version (with a few stylistic changes, sorry about that):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::string s="";
    std::string dummy="";
    while ( s!="exit"){
        s="";
        while (s==""){
            std::cout<<"s = ";
            std::getline(std::cin, s);
        }
        double d;
        std::cout<<"d = ";
        do {
            if (std::cin.fail()){
                std::cin.clear();
                std::getline(std::cin, dummy);
                std::cout << "d = ";
            }
            std::cin>>d;
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        } while (std::cin.fail());
    }
}
```